# Why does assigning an object a value to that of another object, and then reassigning the original object change both objects?

Tags: javascript

I was performing some calculations on the following array of objects:

`array = [ { x: 6, y: 2 }, { x: 7, y: 2 }, { x: 8, y: 2 } ]`

At each iteration, I set each objects equal to it's adjacent except the one at index 0.

```
for (let i = array.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
 array[i] = array[i-1]
}
```

And got the following answer:

`[ { x: 6, y: 2 }, { x: 6, y: 2 }, { x: 7, y: 2 } ]`

Then I set the object at index 0 like so `array[0].x = 5`, and got:

`[ { x: 5, y: 2 }, { x: 5, y: 2 }, { x: 7, y: 2 } ]`

My assumption would've been that the object at index 1 would not have been changed as well. Why is this?

Comment: you assign the same object reference, not the values.

Comment: The object only exists once, at no point are you making a *copy* of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That happens because you are assigning references instead of values:

```
array[i] = array[i-1]
```

You can create a shallow copy of the object using, for example, `Object.assign()`:

```
array[i] = Object.assign({}, array[i-1])
```